# Find Minimum excludant ( MEX )

Tags: algorithm, set, game-theory

I am looking for a algorithm to find [mex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)) but can't find anything uself except this wiki link.

After reading it I pulled up this code:

```
nList = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
nList = set(nList)
mex = 0
for i in nList:
    if i<=mex:
        mex += 1
if mex == max(nList):
    print(mex+1)
else:
    print(mex)
```

So is it correct? Whatever test-cases I have tried seems to work and if not please guide me. 
In terms of time-complexity is this the best way?
Code is in python3 sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally code the mex function as:

```
nList = set(nList)
mex = 0
while mex in nList:
  mex += 1
```

The problem with your code is that the order of iteration over a set is not guaranteed to be in increasing order, so your original code could return the wrong answer sometimes.

The reason your test cases don't turn this up is because I believe Python 3 currently hashes integers to their value modulo a large prime (that can be read in sys.hash_info.modulus), and then constructs sets from lists based on being sorted by their hash value.  In practice, this means that for normal sized integers your sets will return the values in order, and so your code works (but may not on future or alternative implementations of Python 3).

Comment: in terms of time complexity can we do better than this?

Comment: if the input was in sorted order you could do better, otherwise it will be hard to beat

Comment: for each " mex in nList " call does it takes o(n) time? as per  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity . or is it for whole iteration?

Comment: your values will hash to different points as long as they are reasonably sized so you shoul get O(1) per iteration